# How to pass sortable order to hidden field in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to pass the values of a sortable list to a hidden field using the code below, but no luck:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  });

  var idsInOrder = [];

  $("#form_quest").submit(function(){
    $("ul#sortable2 li.card").each(function() { idsInOrder.push($(this).attr('title')); });

    $("#sort_order").val(idsInOrder);
  });  
});
</script>
```

html hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sort_order" id="sort_order" value=""/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing it on the form submit, do it **[when the order has been updated](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update)**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4zxLkfv6/5/

```
var idsInOrder = [];
$('.sortable').sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {
      idsInOrder = [];
      $('.sortable li').each(function() {
          idsInOrder.push($(this).attr('id'));
      });
      $('#sort_order').val(idsInOrder);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain title1,title2,title3 in your field:

```
$("#sort_order").val(idsInOrder.join(','));
```